# Cannot use sudo apt-get update in linux 18.04

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04

This is the output I get when I try to run sudo apt-get update or when I try to install anything.

```
sudo apt-get update 
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not resolve ‘dl.google.com’
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve ‘security.ubuntu.com’
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘security.ubuntu.com’
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve ‘dl.google.com’
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I also cannot access github telling me that github could not be resolved.

Any clue what might cause this?

UPDATE: output from traceroute

```
traceroute dl.google.com
traceroute to dl.google.com (216.58.210.46), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * peer7-et-0-0-1.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (62.172.103.158)  20.930 ms peer8-et-0-1-4.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.252.106)  20.638 ms
 7  109.159.253.235 (109.159.253.235)  22.406 ms 195.99.126.75 (195.99.126.75)  25.586 ms 109.159.253.93 (109.159.253.93)  24.234 ms
 8  * * *
 9  72.14.236.224 (72.14.236.224)  27.654 ms 108.170.234.160 (108.170.234.160)  27.338 ms 74.125.252.128 (74.125.252.128)  28.687 ms
10  * * *
11  * * lhr25s11-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.210.46)  20.101 ms
```

Comment: Network issue? Appears as if non of the PPA's can be reached.

Comment: output from traceroute included above

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a DNS issue. To fix it, you need to ensure that

/etc/resolv.conf has good entries for DNS servers.

Google has public DNS servers that you can use.

So for example, you could add the following 2 lines to the top of your /etc/resolv.conf file (these point at the Google DNS servers) as detailed above:

nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4

In addition, if you use a proxy, be sure that you have created/modified the file /etc/apt/apt.conf to specify your proxy as below:

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://Your_Proxy:Port";

Acquire::https::Proxy "http://Your_Proxy:Port";

Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://Your_Proxy:Port";